# Increase Maxpoolsize in mongoDB using spring data mongoDB(4.2)

Tags: java, mongodb, multithreading, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am getting com.mongodb.MongoWaitQueueFullException.
Mongo version - 4.2 ,
Spring Data MongoDB version - 3.6

How can i increase pool size?
Will increasing pool size would work for me, Currently, i am running mongo on single node inside docker container.

Exception :-

org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Too many threads are already waiting for a connection. Max number of threads (maxWaitQueueSize) of 500 has been exceeded.; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoWaitQueueFullException: Too many threads are already waiting for a connection. Max number of threads (maxWaitQueueSize) of 500 has been exceeded.
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoExceptionTranslator.java:131) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(MongoTemplate.java:2589) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:2457) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:2242) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:2225) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:770) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFindAndDelete(MongoTemplate.java:1920) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.findAllAndRemove(MongoTemplate.java:1905) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.6.RELEASE]
at com.dynamediation.reporting.util.VSProcessorUtil.saveVoiceCallTypeCollection(VSProcessorUtil.java:37) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
at com.dynamediation.reporting.util.VSProcessorUtil$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$888d3dd6.invoke() ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:747) ~[spring-aop-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-aop-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoWaitQueueFullException: Too many threads are already waiting for a connection. Max number of threads (maxWaitQueueSize) of 500 has been exceeded.
at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultConnectionPool.createWaitQueueFullException(DefaultConnectionPool.java:277) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar!/:na]
at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultConnectionPool.get(DefaultConnectionPool.java:96) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar!/:na]
at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultConnectionPool.get(DefaultConnectionPool.java:89) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar!/:na]
at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServer.getConnection(DefaultServer.java:80) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar!/:na]
at com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding$ClusterBindingConnectionSource.getConnection(ClusterBinding.java:98) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar!/:na]
at com.mongodb.ClientSessionBinding$SessionBindingConnectionSource.getConnection(ClientSessionBinding.java:105) ~[mongodb-driver-3.6.3.jar!/:na]
at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:469) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar!/:na]
at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:415) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar!/:na]
at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:711) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar!/:na]
at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:83) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar!/:na]
at com.mongodb.Mongo$3.execute(Mongo.java:826) ~[mongodb-driver-3.6.3.jar!/:na]
at com.mongodb.MongoIterableImpl.execute(MongoIterableImpl.java:130) ~[mongodb-driver-3.6.3.jar!/:na]
at com.mongodb.MongoIterableImpl.iterator(MongoIterableImpl.java:77) ~[mongodb-driver-3.6.3.jar!/:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:2440) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.6.RELEASE]
... 13 common frames omitted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[maxPoolSize](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#mongodb-urioption-urioption.maxPoolSize) is a connection string option.  Set it when you connect to MongoDB.

Comment: Could you please help how to do in Java. I am using Spring Data MongoDB in Spring Boot application